# Proof that $\int_{C}\frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds-\int_C \frac{f(s)}{s-\frac{1}{\bar{z}}}ds=2\pi i f(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic inside and on the unit circle $C$.

Show that, for $0<\mid{z}\mid<1$
$$
2\pi i f(z) = \int_C \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds - \int_c \frac{f(s)}{s-\frac{1}{\overline{z}}}
$$
Using Cauchy's integral formula i got:
$$
\int_C \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds = 2\pi if(z)
$$
and
$$
\int_c \frac{f(s)}{s-\frac{1}{\overline{z}}}=2\pi if(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})
$$
taking one away from the other we get:

$2\pi i(f(z)-f(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}))$

What have I done wrong here, I got close to the answer, but definitely not the answer.

Comment: The second integral is $0$ - there is no "poles".

Comment: Note that $\mid{\frac{1}{\overline z}\mid} = \frac{1}{\mid{\overline z}\mid} = \frac{1}{\mid{z}\mid} > \frac{1}{1} = 1$. Hence, $\mid{\frac{1}{\overline z}\mid}$ is not inside the contour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that, for any $h$ holomorphic on an open set $U$ which contains $D=\{z:|z| \leq 1\}$, $\int_{C} h(z)dz=0$. Now note that $|z|<1$ implies $|\frac{1}{\bar{z}}|=\frac{1}{|z|}>1$. Hence $$\frac{f(s)}{s-\frac{1}{z}}$$ is holomorphic on an open set containing $D$, and you can apply the first observation to conclude that the second integral is $0$.